# Unable to open .php file on browser using http://localhost/dirname

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

On Ubuntu 16.04 when I try to open .php file on browser using http://localhost/vish+all it show blank page and a word 'yes' written on it . And due  to this I am unable to  acess php file on browser.
And I have php7.0 installed on it. What does word 'yes' means.
And how can I find solution for this?

Comment: This question is unanswerable in it's current state. How are you serving the file (nginx? apache? something else?) What does your code look like?  Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but you can only open straight up HTML in your browser. If your file has PHP tags you must serve the file up using a web server such as Apache or Nginx.

Comment: is + a valid URL character?

Answer (score 0):

You must need to verify if the php is a index.php and if is inside the command echo 'yes';
because echo <--- prints any character.
Example:

```
<?php
echo 'yes';
?>
```

also check your php.ini and check if your short_open_tag=On is ON because if is not your code  will not work instead of

Also try to remove "+" from your directory or try to upload a new php called info.php and copy inside there the following code

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?>
```